# How to search through results of instant search Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following code that does an instant search in Outlook, but I am unsure of how now to loop through these results to do further checks.

Any pointers would be gratefully received!

```
Sub SearchByAddress()

    Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim oMail  As Outlook.MailItem

    Set ns = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

          strFilter = "joebloggs@hotmail.com"

    Set myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
         txtSearch = "from:(" & Chr(34) & strFilter & Chr(34) & ") AND " & Chr(34) & "Check" & Chr(34)
         myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Search txtSearch, olSearchScopeAllFolders

    Set myOlApp = Nothing



End Sub
```

Comment: What loop/further checks your trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Application.AdvancedSearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.advancedsearch) instead - it returns an instance of the [Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.search) object.